# check if a string has only some specific words

Tags: javascript, php, regex

i'm using a string with brackets, numbers and logical operators (AND, OR, NOT)
i want to validate my string by checking if user enters the correct operators.

example:

```
(12 AND 13)        //correct
(12 BAND 13)       //incorrect
(12 AND 13 OR 14)  //correct
(12 DNA 13 OR 14)  //incorrect
```

I want to validate this string in either javascript or php,
so a REGEX or a pregmatch would do the job.

EDIT:-

there can be any number of operators in a string.. Plus nested brackets can also exist, like

```
(11 AND 12 AND 13 OR 14 NOT 15)  //correct
((12 AND 13) NOT 14)             //correct
```

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/qS3lD3/2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex like

```
 ^\(\d+(\s+(AND|OR|NOT)\s+\d+)+\)$
```

see example : http://regex101.com/r/qS3tD8/1

**Explanation**

`^` anchors the regex at the begining of the string

`\(` matches `(`

`\d+` one or more digits

`\s` matches space

`(AND|OR|NOT)` matches `AND` `OR` `NOT`

`\)` matches `)`

`$` anchors regex a end of the string

**EDIT**

```
^\(\(?\d+(\s+(AND|OR|NOT)\s+\(?\d+\)?)+\)$
```

matches any number of operators and nested paranthesis as well

example : http://regex101.com/r/qS3tD8/6

Comment: sorry to bother again, but some strings are giving incorrect outputs   `(12 NOT (12 AND 13) NOT 12)  //correct  -- but given incorrect` and `(12 (12 AND 13)) //incorrect -- but given correct` give wrong results

Comment: @test sorry for that mistake check this link http://regex101.com/r/qS3tD8/4. will correct the answer

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/qS3tD8/5 . I think its the parenthesis thats giving the problem.

Comment: @test thank you !!! but the regex is not perfect it only work for the examples in your question. if you want to incoperate something more i would recomend to write some parsers. For example a case where it would fail is removing one of the opening or closing braces